# system settings withing Ui Component Form

Tags: magento2, configuration, uicomponent, system.xml

I want to show a certain text (that is set with a configuration setting from system.xml) within my UI component Form.

The UI component is used in the frontend.
Do i provide it with a DataProvider? And if so how?

Does someone has an idea how this is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add Block with template before your Ui component. In Block class just use `ScopeConfigInterface` to get your text from configuration

Comment: I am using a modal which means the fields are set within the ui_component itself.